# Different viewmodel in partial view and rest of page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out how i can use fully different data on my page compared to what i use in a partial view.

I have a search bar at the top of my website, that top is a partial view that accepts a searchviewmodel and the bottom could be well, anything (search result, a blog, completely unrelated stuff).

Obviously i don't want to "mix" viewmodels, each of them should be unaware of the other (i'm not going to create a class to host both the partial & main viewmodel for each different page).

What is an appropriate way to handle this scenario?

Scenario is

```
  User fills search on the top
 => if model is invalid, redisplay current page with errors (current page could for 
    example be today's wether, requiring WeatherViewModel for main content and 
    SearchViewModel for partial view)
 => else display result page (still need SearchViewModel for top banner 
    and then SearchResultsViewModel for the page)
```

I'm not finding any help online so far from googling (all i found was scenarios where it made sense to create a class to host both sub classes as they were functionally related, which isn't the case here).

My SearchViewModel looks like this:

```
    public class SearchViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string StartCity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EndCity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public SearchType Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public SearchTimeType TimeType { get; set; }
}
```

It corresponds only to the top search and can be present on ANY page regardless of what viewmodel the REST OF THE PAGE uses.

Comment: What does this `SearchViewModel` look like?

Comment: you mean viewmodels for page and search control has to be different but errors wherever occur it has to be shown in the main page

Comment: Ok, so the search is at the top of the page, but isn't there a  controller action that processes the `SearchViewModel` when the user searches? When the user searches, they **GO** to that controller action. So I am unsure why you need to process `SearchViewModel` in all controller actions.

Comment: Well i guess that works if i only want to process searchviewmodel there, but ideally i'd want to have model errors displayed in the source page (not navigate to the controller) if there is an error

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the Search Partial View into the Template outside the @RenderBody().

Your partial View might have a a form to an action that returns the ShowResults View.